# How can I eliminate this error : Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I didn't make use of Expanded widget but I don't know why I keep getting for this error.
**Uncaught exception by widget library, Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget** in four places I can't get where exactly the error is coming from. though it doesn't stop me from using the application but I feel it should be fixed. please can anyone help me?
This is my code below:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/Anchors.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/api/api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  TextEditingController mailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ScaffoldState scaffoldState;

  _showMsg() {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'Invalid Username or Password',
        style: (TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
           FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0.0, 0.4, 0.9],
                colors: [
                  Color(0XFF4CAF50),
                  Color(0xFF388E3C),
                  Color(0xFF075009),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ///////////  background///////////
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                new Container(
                    width: 100.00,
                    height: 100.00,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    )),

                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              left: 30,
                              top: 100,
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Welcome",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 23,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            Card(
                              elevation: 4.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                // child: form(key: _formKey),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    /////////////  Email//////////////

                                    TextField(
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                                      controller: mailController,
                                      cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.account_circle,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                        hintText: "Username",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                                BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                    /////////////// password////////////////////

                                    TextField(
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                                      cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                      controller: passwordController,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      obscureText: true,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.vpn_key,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                                BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                                        hintText: "Password",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    /////////////  LogIn Botton///////////////////
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: FlatButton(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 8,
                                              bottom: 8,
                                              left: 10,
                                              right: 10),
                                          child: Text(
                                            _isLoading ? 'Loging...' : 'Login',
                                            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 15.0,
                                              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.green,
                                        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                        onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _login,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            ////////////   new account///////////////
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => LogIn()));
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  'Forgot Your Password?',
                                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));

    // Gesture ends here
  }

 }
```

this is the picture of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Please add the complete error message

Comment: @JideGuru Please I just updated the question.

Comment: I just wrote an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Positioned` widget inside `Column` widgets in different parts of your code.

> A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack, and the path from
> the Positioned widget to its enclosing Stack must contain only
> StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets

I pasted the above from [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) and it says that a `Positioned` must be descendant of a `Stack` i.e you cannot have a position inside other Widgets aside from a `Stack` widget.

You should remove the `Positioned` widgets from your code. or wrap them with a `Stack` widget

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/Anchors.dart';
import 'package:erg_app/api/api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  TextEditingController mailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ScaffoldState scaffoldState;

  _showMsg() {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'Invalid Username or Password',
        style: (TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0.0, 0.4, 0.9],
                colors: [
                  Color(0XFF4CAF50),
                  Color(0xFF388E3C),
                  Color(0xFF075009),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ///////////  background///////////
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                new Container(
                    width: 100.00,
                    height: 100.00,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    )),

                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Welcome",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 23,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 30),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              // child: form(key: _formKey),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  /////////////  Email//////////////

                                  TextField(
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                                    controller: mailController,
                                    cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                                        Icons.account_circle,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                      hintText: "Username",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  /////////////// password////////////////////

                                  TextField(
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                                    cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                    controller: passwordController,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    obscureText: true,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                                        Icons.vpn_key,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  /////////////  LogIn Botton///////////////////
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 8,
                                            bottom: 8,
                                            left: 10,
                                            right: 10),
                                        child: Text(
                                          _isLoading ? 'Loging...' : 'Login',
                                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                      onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _login,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                          ////////////   new account///////////////
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => LogIn()));
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Forgot Your Password?',
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));

    // Gesture ends here
  }

}
```

Comment: Oh @JideGuru thank you very much. okk so you removed all the **positioned**

Comment: Yes I removed the `Positioned` widgets